# Extracting data from an ANOVA object that is based on the data in R

Tags: r, anova

I am trying to find a less convoluted way to extract data from an `aov` object. Suppose I have a dataset `a` as shown below, and I ran an ANOVA based on the data, resulting in an object named `a.model`. I tried to locate the data by using `str(a.model)`, but haven't been able to find them. Since I know how to extract data from `lm` objects, what I did was using `lm(a.model)$model$score`, which works. But is it possible to directly extract data from `a.model` without first converting an `aov` object to an `lm` object? - I guess this is more out of curiosity than anything because the "extra" step of conversion is not that much more work.

```
a=data.frame(factor1 = rep(letters[1:2], each=10), 
             factor2 = rep(letters[c(1,2,1,2)], each=5), 
             score=sort(rlnorm(20)))
a.model = aov(score~factor1*factor2, data=a)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Output from `aov` also have a component called `model` which contains the data, ie. `a.model$model$score` is identical to `lm(a.model)$model$score`.

Function `names` is useful:

```
> names(a.model)
 [1] "coefficients"  "residuals"    
 [3] "effects"       "rank"         
 [5] "fitted.values" "assign"       
 [7] "qr"            "df.residual"  
 [9] "contrasts"     "xlevels"      
[11] "call"          "terms"        
[13] "model"
```

Another way which is perhaps more convienient and works in more general cases, is to use functions `model.matrix` and `model.frame` which give the desing matrix and the whole model used in formula. In your second example (in comments) you can use `model.frame` to get the data.

Comment: Does it matter whether or not the model is repeated measures? Because if it is repeated measures, the output of `names()` is different. 
`a=data.frame(factor1 = rep(letters[1:2], each=40), factor2 = rep(letters[c(1,2,1,2)], each=20), id = rep(paste("subj", 1:4, sep=""), 5), score=sort(rlnorm(80)))

a.model = aov(score~factor1*factor2 + Error(id/(factor1*factor2)), data=a)
names(a.model)`

Comment: No but using the Error function in the formula causes the the aov work differently. I updated my answer.

Comment: An add up to the answer above and the @Alex's comment the that Alex is right. When we add the 'Error()' in our model, the options above are not valid. What one can do is 'a <- do.call(cbind, lapply(model, summary))' or simply 'unclass(summary(model))'. they give out a list of lists where one can easily access the stats, say by 'a[[2]][['F value]]'.